# Continuity and roots

Tags: real-analysis

I don't understand the 'since' here. In the specific case of the parabola $f'$ what he says is true, but it does not seem to me true in general. Consider (perhaps a bit ironically) $f(x) = x^3 - x$. It has zeroes at -1, 0, and 1. But we could not say that it has the same sign between -1 and 1 for the reason that it is a continuous function.

> Consider, once more, the function $f(x) = x^3 - x$. We have $f'(x) = 3x^2 - 1$.
>   ...
>   Since $f'$ is continuous, and vanishes only at $-\sqrt{1/3}$ and $-\sqrt{1/3}$, we know that $f'$ always has the same sign on the interval $(-\sqrt{1/3}, -\sqrt{1/3})$.

Note that this is a side remark on a chapter otherwise committed to examine how we can graph $f$ from $f'$

Comment: "It has zeroes at -1, 0, and 1. But we could not say that it has the same sign between -1 and 1 ".  You can't say it because there is a zero between $-1$ and $1$.  If there *weren't* a zero between $-1$ and $1$ you most certainly *could* say it.  And you *can* so $f$ is the same sign between $-1$ and $0$.  And between $0$ and $1$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, try tossing out the "since." Suppose the author had said "We know that $f'$ always has the same sign on the interval $(-s, s)$" (where $s = \sqrt{1/3}$). What would you have thought?

If you were me, you'd have thought, "Really? Why?"  And then maybe you'd have thought about the graph of $f'$, and said "it's a parabola...ok...so it's got at worst two 'pieces' on one side of the $x$-axis, and one piece on the other. And the one piece (if there is one) lies between the two roots of $f'$ (if there are roots)." Then you'd figure out that the roots are $s$ and $-s$, so you'd say "OK, we're done!"

And you'd be right...but the author is trying to teach you something as well: you don't need to know how to graph a quadratic to conclude this! Instead, you can say, "If I know a function $g$ has two roots, then between those two roots, its sign is constant." But **wait** .... that's **wrong**. You can only make that conclusion if the function is continuous (or has some other property that's similarly strong). For instance, the function

$$
g(x) = \begin{cases}x - 1 & x \ge 0 \\
x + 1 & x < 0
\end{cases}
$$
has only two roots (at $x = \pm 1$), but its sign is **not** constant on the interval between them. It manages to change sign by being discontinuous.

You can only conclude the constant-sign thing if you know the function's continuous (or something else equally powerful).

And why is continuity good enough? Because of the Intermediate Value Theorem. If the (continuous) function were positive at some point $a$ and negative at some point $b$, both between the two roots, then it'd be zero at some point $c$ between $a$ and $b$, and that would be a *third root, contradicting your assumption of "exactly two roots."

So the author has just shown you how to make an argument that you'll use over and over in real analysis.